# How to aggregate or count from another datarame with constraint?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, aggregate

I have two data.frames which are DF1 and DF2.

DF1 is the passenger record and DF2 is the train record.

I just want to find the user who could take only one train.
What I want to is only choose if there is only one train included in the passenger travel time. The train would be arrive at boarding station after the passenger in, and the train would be arrive at alighting station before the passenger out. DF2$BSEC>DF1$BSEC &DF2$ ASEC

If DF2 meet the constraints, then I want to extract it as below, (e.g.,BSTN is boarding station, ASTN is alighting station)

```
--psuedo code--
DF3<-subset(DF2, BSTN==DF1$BSTN & ASTN==DF1$ASTN & BSEC>DF1$BSEC & ASEC<DF1$ASEC)

if nrow(DF3)==1 then cbind(DF1,DF2)

--my code now--
for(i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  DF1.1<-DF1[i,]
  DF3<-subset(DF2, BSTN1==DF1.1$BSTN & ASTN1==DF1.1$ASTN & BSEC1>DF1.1$BSEC & ASEC1<DF1.1$ASEC)

if(nrow(DF3)==1)(aa<-bind_cols(DF1.1,DF3))
  temp.res<-bind_rows(temp.res,aa)
  }
```

---

However, it takes too long time to calculate with for loop, since the total data of DF1 is about 8,000,000 rows and DF2 is about 100,000,000.

is there any method to calculate faster with aggregate or count packages (functions)?

The data and result what I want to is,

DF1

```
ID  BSTN     ASTN   BSEC    ASEC
1   2520    2516    200079  21071
2   2520    2516    200079  51071   
3   228     2516    300079  31071
```

DF2

```
TRNID   BSTN     ASTN   BSEC    ASEC
1       2520    2516    200080  21061   
2       2520    2516    400079  41231   
3       2520    2516    500079  52171   
4       2520    2516    600079  60101
5       228     2516    300100  31061   
6       228     2516    400079  41231   
7       228     2516    500079  52171   
8       228     2516    600079  60101
```

res

```
ID  BSTN     ASTN   BSEC    ASEC    TRNID   BSTN     ASTN   BSEC    ASEC
1   2520    2516    200079  21071   1       2520    2516    200080  21061
3   228     2516    300079  31071   5       2520    2516    300100  31061
```

THANK YOU!!

Comment: @Ronak Shah -- What I want to is only choose if there is only one train included in the passenger travel time. The train would be arrive at boarding station after the passenger in, and the train would be arrive at alighting station before the passenger out. DF2$BSEC>DF1$BSEC &DF2$ ASEC<DF1$ASEC set as the constraint to apply the logic!! Can u figure it out to solve the problem??!!! please

Comment: @eunlee see https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using *sqldf*

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT a.ID, a.BSEC As df1BSEC,a.ASEC As df1ASEC, b.TRNID, b.BSEC As df2BSEC, b.ASEC As df2ASEC
      FROM df1 a
      LEFT JOIN df2 b on 
      b.BSEC > a.BSEC AND b.ASEC < a.ASEC
             GROUP BY a.ID
             Having COUNT(*) = 1")

  ID df1BSEC df1ASEC TRNID df2BSEC df2ASEC
1  1  200079   21071     1  200080   21061
2  3  300079   31071     5  300100   31061
```

Comment: Holly.... it is incredible..... really appreciate with your comment/code.... it works really fast.... you saved me.... Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your attempt and description this is what I came up with

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {
  inds <- with(df1, BSTN[i] == df2$BSTN & ASTN[i] == df2$ASTN & 
                    BSEC[i] < df2$BSEC & ASEC[i] > df2$ASEC)
  if(sum(inds) == 1) 
      cbind(df1[i, ], df2[inds, ])
}))

#  ID BSTN ASTN   BSEC  ASEC TRNID BSTN ASTN   BSEC  ASEC
#1  1 2520 2516 200079 21071     1 2520 2516 200080 21061
#3  3  228 2516 300079 31071     5  228 2516 300100 31061
```

For every row of `df1` we `cbind` corresponding `df2` row if there is only one row in `df2` which  satisfies the condition.

Comment: I really appreciated with your answer!! i am trying the code that you suggest for my problem!! As possible as it works, I will tell you the 'Thanks' again. Thank you!!